# Loading animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using the following jQuery snippet to make a loading animation run (created in CSS) when a file is selected in an input field and then an upload button is clicked.

The form has **3 input fields** with **3 upload buttons** and is quite flexible. For e.g if a user selects a file in the *first input field* but clicks on the *second upload button* the loading animation should run around the *first input field* only. Another example is that if a user selects a file in the *first input field* and the *second input field* but clicks on the *third upload button* then the loading animation should run in the *first* and *second input fields* only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function() {
        $(".p").each(function(file) {
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $(this).next(".loader").show();
                $(this).next(".loader").find(".spinner").show();
                $(this).next(".loader").find(".UploadBtn").hide();
             }
        });
    });
});
```

The code fails to run in the IF statement function. If i change the code (mentioned below) it will make the animation run but it ends up making the loading animation run in all 3 selection fields even if only one file was selected. This is not what is required but does tell me that the part of the code which has the IF statement breaks down in the code above;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function() {
        $(".p").each(function(file) {
            if  ($(this).val()) {
                $(".loader").show();
                $(".spinner").show();
                $(".UploadBtn").hide();
            }

         })
   });
});
```

I am a beginner level coder and I have spent hours trying to fix this issue but nothing worked. Your help is greatly appreciated!

*HTML snippet added as per recommendation*
(It also has some Python code which was done by my friend) form.photo1, 2 and 3 have class = "p" ;

```
<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo1 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
 loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">

<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo2 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">

<div class="mtl mbl">
{{ form.photo3 }}
</div>
<div class="loader">
<div class="spinner"></div>
loading</div>
<input type="submit" class="UploadBtn btn bm bco mbs mts" style="border-color:#f57c00;" value="Upload">
```

Comment: Your `html` code will be helpful here..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have added the HTML code

Comment: No elements at HTML at Question have `.className` `"p"`

Comment: {{ form.photo1 }}, {{ form.photo2 }} and {{ form.photo3 }} have .className "p". I have updated the post as well.

Comment: Are the `.p` elements `<form>` elements as implied by the name `form.photoX`? Why are you testing the `.val()` of `<form>` elements? As an aside, why do you have three separate *Upload* buttons when they all submit all three files and not just their own adjacent file?

Comment: the three upload buttons are the clients requirement hence they can't be changed. Another requirement is that when ever a file is selected in any selection field (form element) and any of the upload button is clicked then selections fields with a file in them should have a loading animation running around them.